# Can Python's random.seed be affected by a subsequent call to time.sleep?

Tags: python, multithreading, random, random-seed

So, I ran this code with Python 3.10.4:

```py
from random import getrandbits, seed
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from time import sleep
from json import dumps


def function():
    seed(2)
    result = set()
    for _ in range(10):
        # sleep(0.000000000000000000001)
        result.add(format(getrandbits(128), "032x"))

    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":

    futures = []
    result = {}

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        for _ in range(10):
            futures.append(executor.submit(function))

        for future in as_completed(futures):
            for random_number in future.result():

                if random_number not in result.keys():
                    result[random_number] = 0
                result[random_number] += 1

    print(dumps(result, indent=4))
```

I got this result:

```
{
    "ef8acd128b4f2fc15f3f57ebf30b94fa": 10,
    "5c6e433715ba2bdd177219d30e7a269f": 10,
    "4067c3584ee207f8da94e3e8ab73738f": 10,
    "82523e86feac7eb7dc38f519b91751da": 10,
    "cdbd47d364be8049a372db8f6e405d93": 10,
    "d95bafc8f2a4d27bdcf4bb99f4bea973": 10,
    "cf1822ffbc6887782b491044d5e34124": 10,
    "0925e4749b575bd13653f8dd9b1f282e": 10,
    "e6b58de744ab6cce80877b6f71e1f6d2": 10,
    "ffed9235288bc781ae66267594c9c950": 10
}
```

When I uncommented the call to `sleep` above and ran it again, I got this result instead:

```
{
    "d95bafc8f2a4d27bdcf4bb99f4bea973": 6,
    "82523e86feac7eb7dc38f519b91751da": 6,
    "cf1822ffbc6887782b491044d5e34124": 4,
    "cdbd47d364be8049a372db8f6e405d93": 5,
    "4067c3584ee207f8da94e3e8ab73738f": 6,
    "ef8acd128b4f2fc15f3f57ebf30b94fa": 5,
    "e6b58de744ab6cce80877b6f71e1f6d2": 3,
    "5c6e433715ba2bdd177219d30e7a269f": 4,
    "0925e4749b575bd13653f8dd9b1f282e": 5,
    "ffed9235288bc781ae66267594c9c950": 4,
    "6a27e0dfcbf8754472154e76e4c11ab2": 1,
    "e8624fab5186ee32ee8d7ee9770348a0": 1,
    "829a48d422fe99a22c70501e533c9135": 1,
    "bd143fa9b714210c665d7435c1066932": 1,
    "e2520e33e44c50556c71c4a66148a86f": 1,
    "e89204e2e8168561867e5e15bc01bfce": 1,
    "7f81375eecc1cb6347733e847d718d73": 1,
    "a8acb5137c9260dc74e088a9b9492f25": 1,
    "2d3d854e061b90303b08c6e33c729578": 1,
    "74667bffe202849da9643a295a9ac6de": 1,
    "e06f291b2a838af8d5c44a4eb3172062": 1,
    "f4767f26294365b2721dea3bf63f23d0": 1,
    "c8c69069134bccd3e1cf4f589f8e4ce0": 1,
    "3ff98ff387c56473a7a83ee0761ebfd2": 1,
    "5d300cb90706a045defc044a09325626": 1,
    "fec3f6b32e8d4b8a8f54f8ceacaab39e": 1,
    "4da4daeb4f3f87777ad1f45ae9500ec9": 1,
    "8ebdbfe3eb9ac688b9d39cca91551e82": 1,
    "681b8f5896838b769da59b74a6c3181c": 1,
    "af29d115ef24bd625dd961e6830b54fa": 1,
    "ff3fe32a30ffc4eed0a7bd04e85bfcdd": 1,
    "81e220df848b1df78feb994a81167346": 1,
    "dbe53fcafb2147df5ca495fa5a91c89b": 1,
    "c5e2486c44a4a8f69dc8db48e86ec9c6": 1,
    "83844b40ffa9b9f15c14bc4a829e07b0": 1,
    "59cc60b17604e4b4e73695c3e652c71a": 1,
    "2d6c797f8f7d9b782a1be9cd8697bbd0": 1,
    "d08f1bb2531d6460f0caeef038c89b38": 1,
    "97eeab64ca2ce6bc5d3fd983c34c769f": 1,
    "9779ac1f45e9dd320c855fdfa7251af0": 1,
    "d4c0dca8b4c9e755cc9c3adcf515a823": 1,
    "0227eeb7b9d7d01f5769da05d205bbfc": 1,
    "cbd4d3e2d4dec9ef83f0be4e80371eb9": 1,
    "930cdbd30f0ad2a81b2d19a2beaa14a7": 1,
    "7d28f93435339774bb1e386c4fd5079e": 1
}
```

As far as I know, the call to `sleep` should not have any effect in the result of the code. The call to `seed` should set the seed in every thread and from that point onwards the sequence of random numbers produced by every thread should be the same (as it happened when there was no call to sleep), right?

What is also very strange is that only *some* random numbers are repeated among the threads.

What could cause this behavior?

Comment: "The call to seed should set the seed in every thread" <- That would need a per-thread RNG. What you're doing here is having multiple threads modify the single global RNG that Python provides as a convenience. The sleeps promote thread switches, whereas in the version without sleeps it's likely that each thread runs to completion without any intermediate thread switches. Try adding `import sys; sys.setswitchinterval(1e-6)
` to the top of your script and see what happens.

Comment: What Mark D. said. `function` is short. Without the `sleep` calls, each call to `function` probably runs to completion before the next one starts and re-seeds the global PRNG state.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I tried that (actually I had to use `setswitchinterval(1e-18)`, but that is probably not relevant here) and yes, it causes the same behavior as using `sleep`, thanks!

The [`random`  module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) says the implementation is thread safe. Maybe this situation is outside the of scope of what the documentation means with "thread safe"?

Comment: @Ocelotl: Yes, "thread safe" unfortunately means different things to different people. In this context, I think all it means is that you won't be able to crash Python or to corrupt the internal random state by using the various functions from different threads. I think it's also reasonable to assume that the random state is also updated properly on each call, so that e.g., you can't have `random.random()` producing the same result on two different threads. (But see the doc note for `random.gauss`.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson would you like to add your first comment as an answer since it answers this question?